# Performance: SortedDictionary vs SortedSet

Tags: .net, performance, red-black-tree, sortedset, sorteddictionary

Should I maintain

1.) a SortedDictionary(double,struct) 
2.) or just a plain Dictionary(double,struct) plus a SortedSet(double)?

I just want fast insertions. I dont care about retrievals, as I'm not gonna do much lookups. I need sorted nature because, the only lookups I do are going to be on the maximum double or a few maximum doubles.

I feel time performance wise -
Both are same, the `SortedSet<double>` just does extra work. Can you guys confirm?

The part I'm unaware of is whether to maintain the sorting, the `SortedDictionary` moves around just the keys (doubles), or both the keys and values. In the latter case 2.) will outperform 1.), isn't it?

Also, its not clear how `SortedDictionary` is internally implemented. `Sortedset` is red-black tree which is a proven performer.

Comment: Have you done any benchmarking to see which performs better?

Comment: This sounds like a micro-optimization.  Logically, it should take longer to insert into a sorted data structure vs unsorted.  I believe the performance between inserting into sorteddictionary vs sortedset should be identical since they are both using a key of the of same type to sort.  So, the question is do you want 1 structure or 2?

Comment: Given that all you need are the `max` values, why do you need to keep track of all the items?

Comment: I am not exactly sure how many of these max values will be needed at run time.In the worst case, I'll have to get all values,starting from the max value

@brcpar, the struct I am using is kinda heavy ~100 bytes,so you mean when the tree nodes will be moved around and rebalanced in sorteddictionary,its just the double value nodes which will be moved around?and then they have pointers to the struct? is that the case?

or is it that the(double, struct) pair as a whole is moved around for rebalancing? if former, 1.) is the way to go. 
I felt maintaing a sortedset(double) would be less "heavy".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`SortedDictionary<K, V>` is the way to go. Not just because it is the right structure for your usage, but even performance-wise and maintenance-wise it will be just better.

---

> *I just want fast insertions*

1. In the second case you will have to insert both into `Dictionary<K, V>` as well as `SortedSet<K>`. That's two insertions (one O(1) and other O(log n)). I would expect it to be slower than single insertion to a `SortedDictionary<K, V>` (O(log n)).
2. `SortedDictionary<K, V>` is internally implemented as a `SortedSet<KeyValuePair<K, V>>` with comparison being done on the `Key` part of the `KeyValuePair<K, V>`. So if you're satisfied with the performance of `SortedSet<T>`, then there should be no looking back.

> *the sorteddictionary moves around just the keys (doubles), or both the keys and values*

**This is clearly micro-optimization.** It's just a matter of moving around few extra bytes and that will hardly matter.

> *its not clear how sorteddictionary is internally implemented. Sortedset is red-black tree which is a proven performer.*

`SortedDictionary<K, V>` is internally implemented as a `SortedSet<KeyValuePair<K, V>>` with comparison being done on the `Key` part of the `KeyValuePair<K, V>`.  [It is a red-black tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14909853/is-sorteddictionary-a-red-black-tree). So that is proven performer too...

---

Also note that `SortedDictionary<K, V>` will be lighter on memory, as well as, results in faster removal as well as enumeration. The `Dictionary<K, V>`/`SortedSet<K>` hybrid approach will give you faster lookups, but it will have to do a lookup for each key in the dictionary for corresponding value part during enumeration. This is going to be slower.

---

**Alert:** I had not read your comments when I wrote the above !!

> *the struct I am using is kinda heavy ~100 bytes*

If you can change it to class, do it. Moving around 100 bytes wont be nice *if your app is performance critical one*.

I made a quick and dirty `Dictionary<K, V>`/`SortedSet<K>` hybrid structure and tested it.

- Indeed it was faster for a 100 byte struct when it came to insertion (more than twice as fast). Surely there is a penalty (who would create a 100 byte struct?).
- When I changed it to class, they both gave the same insertion performance.
- When I shrunk the size of the struct, even then the insertion performance was comparable.

So my suggestion is switch to a class and use `SortedDictionary<K, V>`. If you are stuck with the struct, then `Dictionary<K, V>`/`SortedSet<K>` will be better. Good q, and +1.

Comment: Just a nitpick. In big-O notation, O(1) + O(log N) is not defined as greater or less than O(log N). All you can say if that is the only info you are given is it's ambiguous.